# Attempted import error: 'ReactReduxContext' is not exported from 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to setting up a new react-admin console (following the offcial tutorial : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html). The current version of react-admin is 3.3.1.

But when execute command `yarn start` the following error occured  :

```
./node_modules/ra-core/esm/core/CoreAdminContext.js
Attempted import error: 'ReactReduxContext' is not exported from 'react-redux'.
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Delete your yarn lock / package lock and `yarn install`.

As per this [thread](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4200)

> The problem comes from duplicate Redux packages, coming from duplicate
>   react-admin dependencies, coming from an outdated data provider
>   (designed for 2.9 while react-admin is in 3.x). Either upgrade your
>   data provider, or downgrade react-admin to 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

Update your react-redux to the latest version. In my case, i updated to 7.2.4

```
npm install react-redux@latest
```

or

```
npm install react-redux@7.2.4
```

Comment: Solved the issue for me!