# Failed to compile - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

Can anybody help me with this?

./node_modules/connected-react-router/esm/ConnectedRouter.js

151:35-52 'react-redux' does not contain an export named 'ReactReduxContext'.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741247/attempted-import-error-reactreduxcontext-is-not-exported-from-react-redux

Comment: didn't work @ChrisG

Comment: Try to downgrade the version of react-redux maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your node_modules directory and run `npm install` or `yarn` (if you are using yarn already)

Comment: try to delete yarn.lock / package.lock files and install again

Comment: i deleted node_modules, and cleared, nothing worked!